# How do I calculate the Amount value for the each row, without replacing the newest amount value. (Angular)

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-forms, angular-changedetection, angular-arrays

[image: quantity x price= amount]

Adding the Rows. Here getting the quantity and the price value using the change event.
`

```
 <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input
                  class="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  id="newdescription"
                  [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.description"
                  name="newdescription"
                  placeholder="Description"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input
                  class="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  id="newstudent_quantity"
                  [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.student_quantity"
                  name="newstudent_quantity"
                   (change)="getQuantity($event)"
                  placeholder="Quantity"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 m-1 mt-3">
                <input
                  class="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  id="newprice"
                  [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.price"
                  name="newprice"
                   (change)="getPrice($event)"
                  placeholder="Price"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-end mt-1">
                <button
                  class="btn btn-default "
                  type="button"
                  (click)="addFieldValue()"
                >
                  <i class="nav-icon fas fa-plus icon-green"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

`This is the table after adding rows`

```
  <div class="card" style="background-color: #f3f3f3">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4>Payment Details</h4>
                
                  <div
                    *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index"
                    class="col-md-12"
                  >
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="price"> Description </label>
                        <input
                          [(ngModel)]="field.description"
                          class="form-control"
                          id="description"
                          type="text"
                          name="{{ field.description }}"
                          ngModel
                          required
                          disabled
                        />

                        <label for="price"> Student Quantity </label>
                        <input
                          [(ngModel)]="field.student_quantity"
                          class="form-control"
                          id="student_quantity"
                          type="number"
                          name="{{ field.student_quantity }}"
                          value=""
                          ngModel
                          required
                          disabled
                        />
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="price"> Price </label>
                        <input
                          [(ngModel)]="field.price"
                          id="price"
                          class="form-control"
                          type="number"
                          name="{{ field.price }}"
                          ngModel
                          required
                          disabled
                        />

                        <label for="amount"> Amount </label>
                        <input
                          class="form-control"
                          type="number"
                          name=""
                          ngModel
                          value="{{ amount }}"
                          required
                          disabled
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 mt-1 d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <button
                          class="btn btn-default align-right"
                          type="button"
                          (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)"
                        >
                          <i class="nav-icon fas fa-trash-alt icon-red"></i>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

`

this is the .ts file code

`

```
  newAttribute: any = {};
  fieldArray: Array<any> = [];
  quantity: any;
  price: any;
  amount: any;

  addFieldValue() {
    this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute);
    this.newAttribute = {};
  }

  deleteFieldValue(index: number) {
    this.fieldArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
  
  getPrice(event: any) {
  
    this.price = event.target.value;
    console.log(this.price);
  }
  getQuantity(event: any) {
    this.quantity = event.target.value;
    this.amount = this.price  * this.quantity ;
    console.log("amount" + this.amount);
  }
```

`
I multiplied the this.quantity with the this.price and get the amount value
I want to get the amount value by calculating each row quantity value multiplied by the price(without replacing the newest amount value for every amount value in the table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct `amount` for each row, you will need to make sure it is part of the `fieldArray` array. Your problem is that you only have 3 properties in your `newAttribute` when you push it into `fieldArray`. Another issue is that you then use the `amount` in the table which is global and shared by all of the items.

Below is a simplified example for your case.

Please try to avoid use `any` type since it defeat the purpose of using TypeScript. I created an `Item` type which has 4 properties:

- `description`.
- `price`.
- `quantity`.
- `total`.

To avoid sharing the `total` (`amount` in your case), each item must have its own `total`. This way, when we loop through the `items`, we can access its `total`.

#### example.component.ts

```js
type Item = {
  readonly description: string;
  readonly price: number;
  readonly quantity: number;
  readonly total: number;
};

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  
  public description = '';
  public price = 0;
  public quantity = 0;

  public items: Item[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  public addItem() {
    
    const newItem = {
      description: this.description,
      price: this.price,
      quantity: this.quantity,
      total: this.price * this.quantity
    };

    this.items.push(newItem);
  }

  ...

}
```

#### example.component.html

```html
<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="description" placeholder="Description">
  <input [(ngModel)]="price" placeholder="Price">
  <input [(ngModel)]="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">

  <button (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
</div>

<!-- Loops through all the added items and display them -->

<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ul>
    <li>{{item.description}}</li>
    <li>{{item.price}}</li>
    <li>{{item.quantity}}</li>
    <li>{{item.total}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I modified the code by only adding this part of the code.  addFieldValue() {
    this.newAttribute = {
      description: this.description,
      price: this.price,
      quantity: this.quantity,
      totalAmount: this.amount,
    };
    this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute);
    this.newAttribute = {};

  }                                                                                      ............now It's working.

Comment: @OnellaNatalie Yes, that's basically all you have to do. I added the simplified version so you can learn to write better code. Please accept this answer by clicking on the Check mark so other users won't try to re-answer this question again.